# set the distance between ticks in gridspec

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to draw two 1-d series on top of each other, meaning, without any vertical spacing and I use subplot2grid as I have multiple subplots. The code below alines the lines to top most and bottom most. how can I draw adjacent lines?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0,0))
xvalues = range(0,10)
yvalues = np.ones_like(xvalues)
ax.scatter(xvalues, yvalues)
ax.scatter(xvalues, np.add(yvalues, 1))
ax.set_yticks([1,2])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What determines a line to be "adjacent" to another line? I would say both sets of dots are adjacent, because there is nothing in between. But if you have a different definition, please clearly state how you would like your plot to look like.

Comment: I mean, there should be no gap/white space between lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap between the groups of points is due to the fact that matplotlib autoscales the plot to have 5 percent of the difference between the minimum and maximum point on the axes as padding on each side. If minimum is 1 and maximum is 2, the plot hence ranges from ~0.95 to ~2.05.

Of course you can change the limits, e.g.

```
ax.set_ylim(-5,8)
```

would produce a plot like

[image]